# How to Query Data From Firebase Into AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Hope some of you can provide me with some suggestions on how to Query Data From Firebase into my HTML Page.

Controller

```
.controller('cloudCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$firebaseArray' ,//  $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseArray) {
var ref2 = firebase.database().ref().child("info");
var sync = $firebaseArray(ref2);
console.log(sync.toString());

sync.orderBychild('name').endAt(3).on('child_added', function(snap){
    console.log('added', snap.val())
})

}])
```

HTML5 File

```
  <div ng-controller="cloudCtrl">
  <button ng-click="Load()">Load User</button>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using angularfire ? The $firebaseArray injection suggests that but just to be sure !

Comment: Yes i'm using angularfire, any suggestions to help because i have problems querying from Firebase

Comment: if my answer helped you, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using angularfire, you can do it this way:

```
$scope.load = function() {
    $scope.result = firebase.database().ref().child("info").orderByChild('name').endAt(3);
}
```

Be careful concerning the camelCase on `orderByChild`.

You only need to watch the data if you want an event to occur when a child is added. For example, send a notification when a new message is available. Otherwise the database works in realtime, so if you modify a the name in info (directly in the firebase console) it will be available and updated in your scope.

There is one other way to do this which might come in handy while you're preparing your app:

```
$firebaseArray(yourRef).$loaded().then(function(result) {
    $scope.result = result;
})
```

This will handle the promise while you're fetching the data. That might be useful if you want to show a loader while fetching the data which you would show before that function and hide once it is done.

Hope it helps !